# How to define a handler mapping for processing an html page as aspx on Azure Web App

Tags: .net, azure

We have an application that we're trying to move to an Azure Web App. This app has some HTML pages that contain ASP code so the HTML pages need to be processed by the ASP/ASPX engine.

On IIS we defined a handler mapping for "*.html" as "System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler". How would we do the same sort of thing in the Azure Web App environment?

Answer (score 0):

@MB43, Base on my experience, we can directly deploy our ASP application on Azure Web app. What's error your application occur?

> On IIS we defined a handler mapping for "*.html" as "System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler". How would we do the same sort of thing in the Azure Web App environment?

I recommend you can create web.config into your project and add the handler into system.web section.